# Are Phantom's barriers weaker in the back?

Tags: mass-effect-3

According to the [Javik/Unique dialogue wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Javik/Unique_dialogue#Spontaneous):

> During the battle with the Phantoms, Javik remarks that the Phantoms'
>   barriers appear to be unidirectional and suggests they shoot them in
>   the backs.

But this is not a strategy noted in the wiki entry for [phantom tactics](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Phantom#Tactics).

Is this an actual game mechanic/weakness for battling phantoms? Or will attacking them from behind (while they have barriers up) still inflict the same amount of damage?

Also, I assume that this would only apply to weapon-based attacks and not biotic and tech powers that effect barriers, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried this several times in co-op, without any apparent benefit. Javik's remark seems to just be a bit of interesting lore that is not in the game itself.

Comment: Well, there is the benefit that if you're shooting them in the back they're not shooting you with those nasty palm-blasters. ;)

Comment: Haha, true, they have a straight up aimbot with those pistols. But as far as shields go, there is no difference.